# Building NodeJS Lambda - same source, different SHA hash

Tags: npm, aws-lambda, node-modules, terraform, circleci

I'm having interesting issue and I can't point my finger on the cause. Here is the story.

My goal is to manage Lambda functions with Terraform, using CircleCI as orchestrator. Process looks like this:

> GitHub repository -> CircleCI build (npm install && zip) -> aws s3 sync ZIP to S3 -> Terraform picks up ZIP from S3 -> if SHA is different, deploy to Lambda.

It all works pretty well with one little problem. If I run the whole process twice, with no change in GitHub repository, Terraform always reports new SHA hash:

> source_code_hash: "mx56e7pMbBdftYHes+pETvjFZInvKsP92vtZ5URqyJY=" => "dhe66opfifDLEr7wI+Ie9UE6ioUiG8hTajuPhctA+W0="

It seems the issue lies somewhere around `npm install` process, which perhaps do always something slightly different, thus result is also different. I don't think, that ZIPing folder should cause troubles, it's simple `zip -r file.zip *`.

Any explanation of this behaviour, please?

Comment: Have you tested using the same ZIP file? Do you have a package lock file?

Comment: I will admit a don't know what you mean by "tested" and "package lock file". I simply run `npm install`, then `npm test`, then `zip -r file.zip *` and result is send to S3 bucket.

Comment: Try adding the `--no-extra` argument to your zip file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm install` with versions 4 or less is non-deterministic so there is no guarantee that your `npm install` in different builds will be the same.

`npm` solved it with version 5's `package-lock.json`. Try it again using the latest version of `npm`.

Or, you can try `yarn` or `pnpm`. Both are alternative package managers that aim to use deterministic installs.